# Animated background image not showing in safari

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a fullscreen background image with a little animation (zooming in and out).
It works fine in most browsers, except safari. The background image isn't even showing.
I think it has something to do with the absolute positioning?

The code:

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/500/500/) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 9s infinite;
  animation: zoom 9s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Many Thanks!

EDIT:

After examining my code, it turned out it was the absolute positioning of the .background class that was the guilty one...
I edited my code like this and everything worked in safari:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(../assets/background-large.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 90s infinite;
   animation: zoom 90s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1,1); transform:scale(1,1); }
50% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.2,1.2); transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);transform:scale(1,1); }
}
@keyframes zoom {
0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1,1); transform:scale(1,1); }
50% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.2,1.2); transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);transform:scale(1,1); }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Safari has some issues with `background-size: cover`. Not sure if that's the issue here, but that might be worth looking into.

Comment: Please try to reproduce your issue here, inside the question, using a SO snippet (`<>` button). From what I see you're using quite a few properties that Safari has issues with, such as `transform`, `background-size` and *flexbox* related properties. Any single one of them could be the culprit and without experiencing the bug it's really hard to tell what you're trying to achieve and where it fails. Also, as a general rule, try to write un-prefixed CSS and run it through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). Staying on top of browser bugs is a full time job, which you don't want.